# apache smf refresh does what?

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris, smf

Morning,

I am trying to determine what svcadm refresh apache22 does.  We have had an issue with connectivity to apache this week where nobody can access anything that apache helps serve up.  Doing a refresh seems to let users back in again, but over time (@ 4 hours) we get the same issue (session timeouts).

Does svcadm refresh just read the config files/certs?  We seem to see a lot of children processes in a graceful state after refresh (that number keeps climbing.  Is the refresh doing this, or does refresh just help reveal what is going on?

A better understanding of what refresh does would be helpful as it is short of stopping/starting the apache server, which helps maintain business for some critical things.

Answer (score 5):

`svcs -l apache22` shows that the SMF service manifest can be found in
`/lib/svc/manifest/network/http-apache22.xml`.

Looking at the manifest, it shows that the refresh method is defined as:

```
            <exec_method
                    type='method'
                    name='refresh'
                    exec='/lib/svc/method/http-apache22 refresh'
                    timeout_seconds='60' />
```

Looking at `/lib/svc/method/http-apache22` when called with an argument ("$1") of *refresh* it passes the *graceful* command to Apache’s apachectl script.

Apache documents that command at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html#graceful.

Comment: So, to sum it up, `svcadm refresh apache22` will give you what Apache calls a "graceful restart". To OP:   You really *should* accept this answer from alanc. It is very carefully explained.